# How to deny access to the method if there is no value passed, or value is invalid?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

So I have this method inside one of my Controllers that I use to edit content:

```
public function edit($id){
            $data;//some data that i gather
            $this->load->view('admin/layouts/main',$data);
        }
}
```

And well I can redirect if `$id` is empty, and display a message, something like this:

```
public function edit($id){
  if(empty($id)){
    redirect('admin/articles');
    //here some session variable to store message that i display later
  }
  $data;//some data that i gather
  $this->load->view('admin/layouts/main',$data);
}
```

And for example if I will try to access my method like this: `host.com/controller/method/id` and if `id` will be empty it will redirect me.

But how do i check if `id` that I pass is correct, and there is a real article in my database, that has corresponding `id` and can be edited?

P.S. I use CodeIgniter as a framework.

Comment: send default value like this `public function edit($id=0){//'check if $id=0;if so return  else continue)` >you can use `$id=null` or `$id=''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
public function edit($id = 0){
    // setting $id zero if not passed

    // check $id is integer and > 0
    ctype_digit($id) or redirect('admin/articles');

    // check record exists in your table 
    $result = $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => $id));

    // $result will be false if no record found
    $result or redirect('admin/articles');

    $data = array();

    // if you need that in view
    $data['id']     = $id;
    $data['result'] = $result;

    $this->load->view('admin/layouts/main',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the id you can always use the  is_integer function. And for the article, all you can do is trying to get the article by it's id and redirecting if you don't find any.

Answer (score 1):

After you validate the contents of the `id` (i.e. is a numeric one), you need to query the database by that `id`. If the query returns nothing, it means the `id` is not in the database, and you can redirect to the `articles` page.